# Block Encoding format in PKCS

Tags: rsa, pkcs#1

In PKCS block encoding format for RSA what is difference in Block type 01 and 02? And when are they used?

Comment: In the padding schemes, 0x00 0x01 is used for signing operations, 0x00 0x02 is used for PKCS1 encryption padding.  If that's what you mean.

Comment: [Read it for yourself](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2313).

Comment: Thanks for answering the query.

In the reference link provided above it says: "For a private- key operation, the block type shall be 00 or 01. For a public-key operation, it shall be 02."

Does it mean signing as the private - key operation and verification as public key operation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313#section-8.1 (Thanks, James):

> **8.1 Encryption-block formatting**

A block type BT, a padding string PS, and the data D shall be
formatted into an octet string EB, the encryption block.

> 

```
          EB = 00 || BT || PS || 00 || D .           (1)
```

> 

The block type BT shall be a single octet indicating the structure of
the encryption block. For this version of the document it shall have
value 00, 01, or 02. For a private- key operation, the block type
shall be 00 or 01. For a public-key operation, it shall be 02.

<sub>It's worth noting that the phrase "block type" does not appear in the PKCS#1 v2.0 RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2437)</sub>

Later we see the verification half:

> 

9.4 Encryption-block parsing

> 

The encryption block EB shall be parsed into a block type BT, a
padding string PS, and the data D according to Equation (1).

> 

It is an error if any of the following conditions occurs:

> 

- The encryption block EB cannot be parsed
  unambiguously (see notes to Section 8.1).
- The padding string PS consists of fewer than eight
  octets, or is inconsistent with the block type BT.
- The decryption process is a public-key operation
  and the block type BT is not 00 or 01, *or the decryption
  process is a private-key operation and the block type is
  not 02*.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Using the terminology from RFC2313:

- Signature Generation is an encryption process which is a private-key operation (BT=01)
- Signature Verification is a decryption process which is a public-key operation (BT=01)
- Initiate Key Transfer / Enveloping is an encryption process which is a public-key operation (BT=02)
- Receive Key Transfer is a decryption process which is a private-key operation (BT=02).

RFC 2437 (PKCS#1 2.0) replaced many of these terms, and got rid of the block type notion altogether.  That byte is simply dictated to be `01` for PKCS#1 signature formatting, and dictated to be `02` for PKCS#1 encryption.  That byte isn't fixed for either OAEP (encryption) or PSS (signing) padding schemes.